# Is it required to use -> operator when calling a member function in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax

I have a class like

```
class Date{
 public:
  Date(int year, int month, int date);
  Date(const Date &d);
  Date &operator=(const Date &d);

  bool isHoliday();
  void addDays(int days);
}
```

In my `addDays()` implementation, I need to make a call to `isHoliday()`. I have the following two options, both of which seem to be allowed by the compiler.

Option 1:

```
void Date::addDays(int days) {
 if (this->isHoliday()) {
  // body
 }
}
```

Option 2:

```
void Date::addDays(int days) {
 if (isHoliday()) {
  // body
 }
}
```

Is there any difference between the two definitions? Which is the correct one to use? Thanks.

EDIT: The referenced duplicate question indeed answers my question. Just couldn't find it as I was searching by `->`. I can't delete this now, but do refer to that question for a good number of answers.

Comment: There is no difference, in this case, and both are correct.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks. Is there preference? Like which option the professional `c++` engineers tend to use?

Comment: @swdon It's usually a matter of convention or clarity. If it's obvious in the context that the identifier is a member, it's not needed. If there's a doubt or using `this->` helps me it clear you might as well use it.

Comment: Professional C++ engineers use the convention set by the team they work with. Coding style is about culture, not absolute truth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference here. `isHoliday()` calls the method on the `this` object already. so explicitly saying `this->isHoliday()` isn't required and does the same thing.

In that regard both are "correct to use" as it comes down on personal preference. Around where I work we use `isHoliday()` instead of `this->isHoliday()` as it reduces code clutter but this isn't the de facto standard.